# Wcf Service how to deploy to production server?

Tags: .net, wcf

Can any body help me regarding

1) How to design a WCF service

2) After designing WCF service how to move it from the development environment to production server.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has very good documentation for this:

[Developing and Deploying WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258442.aspx)